# Filament - Disable a field

Tags: laravel-filament

I'm writing a form in filament v2 with a radio that selects between 3 fields

Based on that radio the fields should be disabled and nulled

I'm using `reactive()` in combination with disabled function but it doesn't react it doesn't change

If a change the disabled for hidden it works well

This is the code of the relation manager

```php
public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->columns(1)->schema(function (RelationManager $livewire) {
                $parameter = $livewire->getOwnerRecord();
                $field = "";
                switch ($parameter->type) {
                    case 'I':
                        $field = TextInput::make('value')->required()->mask(
                            fn (TextInput\Mask $mask) => $mask->numeric()->integer(),
                        );
                        break;
                    case 'F':
                        $field = TextInput::make('value')->required()->mask(
                            fn (TextInput\Mask $mask) => $mask->numeric()->decimalPlaces(2),
                        );
                        break;
                    case 'B':
                        $field = Select::make('value')->required()->translateLabel()->options(["TRUE" => "Verdadero", "FALSE" => "Falso"]);
                        break;
                    case 'D':
                        $field = DatePicker::make('value')->translateLabel()->weekStartsOnMonday()->displayFormat('d/m/Y');
                        break;
                    case 'T':
                        $field = TimePicker::make('value')->translateLabel()->displayFormat('H:i:s');
                        break;
                    default:
                        $field = TextInput::make('value')
                            ->required()
                            ->maxLength(255);
                        break;
                }
                return [
                    Radio::make('radio')->options(['T' => 'Todos'])->label('')->default('T')->reactive()->afterStateUpdated(function (callable $set) {
                        $set('group_id', null);
                        $set('rol_id', null);
                        $set('user_id', null);
                    }),
                    Grid::make(2)->schema([
                        Radio::make('radio')->options(['G' => 'Grupo'])->label('')->reactive()->afterStateUpdated(function (callable $set) {
                            $set('rol_id', null);
                            $set('user_id', null);
                        }),
                        Select::make('group_id')
                            ->label('')
                            ->options(Group::all()->pluck('name', 'id'))
                            ->searchable()
                            ->disabled(fn (Closure $get) => $get('radio') != 'G')
                    ]),
                    Grid::make(2)->schema([
                        Radio::make('radio')->options(['R' => 'Rol'])->label('')->reactive()->afterStateUpdated(function (callable $set) {
                            $set('group_id', null);
                            $set('user_id', null);
                        }),
                        Select::make('rol_id')
                            ->label('')
                            ->options(Role::all()->pluck('name', 'id'))
                            ->searchable(),
                    ]),
                    Grid::make(2)->schema([
                        Radio::make('radio')->options(['U' => 'Usuario'])->label('')->reactive()->afterStateUpdated(function (callable $set) {
                            $set('group_id', null);
                            $set('rol_id', null);
                        }),
                        Select::make('user_id')
                            ->label('')
                            ->options(User::all()->pluck('email', 'id'))
                            ->searchable(),
                    ]),
                    $field,
                ];
            });
    }
```

Form looks like this

I want that the selection of a radio disable the no correpondent selects